# How to use alias_method in Haml to escape html?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

What I want to do is using an alias method (defined in a ruby file) in Haml view.

I defined an alias method like following:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'haml'

helpers do
  include Haml::Helpers
  alias_method :h, :html_escape
end

class App < Sinatra::Base

  use Rack::MethodOverride

  # ...

end
```

Then I used method `h()` in a Haml view like following:

```
- @notes.each do |note|
  %article{:class => note.complete? && "complete"}
    %p
      =h note.content
```

But I got an error when I opened the page:

> NoMethodError - undefined method `h' for #:
>
> ...

When I use `Haml::Helpers.html_escape()` directly on the haml file, there's no problem:

```
%p
  = Haml::Helpers.html_escape note.content
```

How can I use my alias method in haml files without errors?

Thanks for any advices or corrections to this questions.

Comment: A lot of that notation is unfamiliar to me, but shouldn't the alias go inside the module where html_escape is defined?

Comment: Yes, and I found that `=html_escape note.content` works well in haml, not verbose `=Haml::Helpers.html_escape note.content`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helpers are getting defined in Application. Instead define them in your class like this:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  helpers do
    include Haml::Helpers
    alias_method :h, :html_escape
  end

  # ...

end
```

or in Base like this:

```
Sinatra::Base.helpers do
  include Haml::Helpers
  alias_method :h, :html_escape                                                                                                                    
end
```